# LDAP Query Attribute Size

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

LDAP Server is holding a big file and don't have a separate attribute to give the file size. So I have to download the entire file to get the file size. Is there anyway to get the attribute size alone with-out downloading the attribute content?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you're looking for but the schema might give you the attribute length (not the actual size of the data stored in the attribute).

```
ldapsearch -b cn=schema -s base "(objectclass=*)"
```

Comment: Thanks. But as you said, it is not, what am I looking for. Already suggested to add a field to store the attribute value length.